# Dismiss open/done installation dialog Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to update my apk with user knowledge, i.e. the user have to accept the permissions and click on the native install dialog button of android. 
To start this installation I use the following code:

```
File file = ContentUtils.getFileForResourceId(this, resourceId);
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

After the user accepts all permission and the android system installed the package successfully my application will redirect the user to a specific activity of the application, without showing the [Android finish installation dialog](http://i1048.photobucket.com/albums/s374/luispereira268/annoying_dialog_zps2bed5e3c.png). For this I use Broadcast Receiver that is listening when a package was added or replaced.

The problem is that once the user did an update the previous [Android finish installation dialog](http://i1048.photobucket.com/albums/s374/luispereira268/annoying_dialog_zps2bed5e3c.png) will appear every time the user clicks on the native installation dialog cancel button or the cancel button of [user data dialog](http://i1048.photobucket.com/albums/s374/luispereira268/dialog_zpsa7f72038.png).

Is there any way to just dismiss the android finish installation dialog, or to disable it?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the extra `EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT` to the intent worked for me, like so:

```
promptInstall.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true)
```