# Dismiss android dialog "installing app"

Tags: android, android-install-apk

The following gif shows how the app "Amazon Underground" dismiss the dialog "installing app" after doing click on install button

[image: dismiss dialog when click on install]

Also, Amazon Underground apparently knows when user clicks on cancel button.

[image: detect cancel dialog]

Similar questions:

[Dismiss open/done installation dialog Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193683/dismiss-open-done-installation-dialog-android)

[Android handle cancel event when app install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893356/android-handle-cancel-event-when-app-install)

[android programmatically update apk and see the result of the installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569647/android-programmatically-update-apk-and-see-the-result-of-the-installation)

I would like to know how to do that programmatically.
Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

**Update:**

I've uploaded a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhfagMgu0CE) to Youtube where you can see the "Amazon installation process" compared with "Normal installation process". In second 22, I tap on install button and Amazon App dismiss/hides/close the dialog

Answer (score 0):

> The following gif shows how the app "Amazon Underground" dismiss the dialog "installing app" after doing click on install button

No, it does not. This is a screencast of the user tapping on the install button. You can see the white dot of the "show pointer touches" developer option in the screencast.

> Also, Amazon Underground apparently knows when user clicks on cancel button.

[An `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` `Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE) can have `EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT` on API Level 14+ to find out when the user installs the app or rejects the installation.

Comment: I did the screencast. When I tap on the install button, the dialog changes showing a progressbar, and when the app is installed the dialog changes again and show the buttons done/open. But Amazon undergroun dismiss the dialog after tapping on the install button. (Sorry for muy english)

Comment: with EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT now I know when the user rejects the installation, but I have to wait until the app is installed to get RESULT_OK. What I would like to know is how Amazon knows when the user tap on install button and how can hide/dismiss/cancel this dialog