# How to pass extra data after installing an app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, apk, extra

I am installing an app programmatically in Android Studio. I am downloading the apk file and then building and launching the `Intent`:

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
context.startActivity(intent)
```

The main problem is that that app (the one that will be installed) needs an `Extra` called `GUID`. This is how I launch the app with that `Extra`:

```
val intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(applicationData.packageName)
intent?.let { i: Intent ->
    i.putExtra("GUID", loggedUserSingleton.guid)
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

I need to launch the app with that `Extra` but Android asks the user if they want to open it after the installation:

[image: Dialog asking the user]

I tried to put this line `i.putExtra("GUID", loggedUserSingleton.guid)` inside the installation `Intent` but is useless.

Is there an option to not show that dialog? Or maybe make the 'Open' option allow you to pass the `Extra`?

Comment: I don't hink that you can pass arguments to the newly opened app if the user uses the open option in the dialog. Therefore omitting the dialog would be the way to go. Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/q/23193683/150978?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an option to not show that dialog?

What the app installer UI does is up to Google and device manufacturers. It will vary by OS version and device model. You cannot control this.

That said, using `ACTION_VIEW` to install an app has been deprecated for some time. If you use `PackageInstaller`, you may have somewhat more control. FWIW, I cover the use of `PackageInstaller` in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Q/pages/chap-pkg-001.html) of [this free book of mine](https://commonsware.com/Q).

> Or maybe make the 'Open' option allow you to pass the Extra?

That too is not an option. Usually, "Open" will do the same thing that the launcher would, and a launcher is not going to know anything about this extra.